# ng-hide on <shape> in NgMap is not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-hide, ng-map

I'm trying to use ng-hide to hide polylines whose particular value is empty.
But its not workin , i'm getting a black polyline and i can't get rid of it.

```
<ng-map center="{{lat}},{{lng}}" disable-default-u-i="true" zoom="15">
                 <shape   ng-repeat="street in streets | filter : query.status" ng-hide="street.status.length === 0"
                          name="polyline" 
                          path="[
                            [{{street.viewport.northeast.lat}}, {{street.viewport.northeast.lng}}],
                            [{{street.viewport.southwest.lat}}, {{street.viewport.southwest.lng}}]
                          ]"
                          geodesic="true"
                          stroke-color="{{street.status | streetColor}}"
                          stroke-opacity="1.0"
                          stroke-weight="10">
                  </shape>
            </ng-map>
```

Comment: It's a good news if it's now working :)

Comment: i think he meant NOT, it's a typo!

Comment: Yeah, I got that, thanks ;)

Comment: Jokes aside, what about using `ng-if` or some conditional hidden class? Are you sure `street.status` is an empty array?

Answer (score 0):

May be you don't have status property in all the objects so **ng-hide is not setting true**. Change ng-hide to this, :

```
ng-if="street.status.length > 0"
```

Comment: Or even `ng-if="street.status.length"`.